# How to make 2 click-to-expand elements on the same line when expanding only the first element?

Tags: html, css

I'm using the following CSS to display two elements compactly.

```css
.trigger,

/* to hide the checkbox and for more general use */

.gone,
.hidden {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
  z-index: -999999;
  top: -999999px;
  margin: -1px;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  height: 1px;
  width: 1px;
  min-height: 0;
  min-width: 0
}

label {
  cursor: pointer
}

.fullverbtable {
  display: none
}

.trigger:checked~.fullverbtable {
  display: block
}

label {
  font-family: 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  color: white;
  background-color: #ff4b54;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 0px 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.verb {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="verb">
  <label for="aimer_larousse_ef_active_10">Conjugaison (voix active)</label>
  <input class="trigger" id="aimer_larousse_ef_active_10" type="checkbox">
  <div class="fullverbtable">
    <link href="larousse_ef.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">abcaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div>
</div>

<div class="verb">
  <label for="aimer_larousse_ef_passive10">Conjugaison (voix passive)</label>
  <input class="trigger" id="aimer_larousse_ef_passive10" type="checkbox">
  <div class="fullverbtable">
    <link href="larousse_ef.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">xyzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz</div>
</div>
```

When expanding both 2 elements, the display is very fine.

[image]

I hope the result when expanding only the first element as

[image]

Could you please explain on how to do so?

Comment: And if you click only on `passive` what happens? where should `xyz` go?

Comment: @Baro When expand an element, that element will appear just as a normal paragraph, beginning from the far left. In my case, it is at the same position as `abc`.

Comment: @Baro Anyway, thank you so much for your interest in my question :)

Comment: if the answer does not suffice, you'll need to trigger some classes with javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought I understood your question if I'm right you want to create something like accordion by using `checkboxes` but the `checkboxes` can all be check and even the y share name that's I used the `radio`
to do so, and I don't want go on you with an invalid HTML that's why you'll find I edit too much but it's simple you'll find what you want

```css
.trigger {
  display: none;
}

label {
  cursor: pointer
}

.fullverbtable_1,
.fullverbtable_2 {
  display: none;
}

input[id="aimer_larousse_ef_active_10"]:checked~.fullverbtable_1,
input[id="aimer_larousse_ef_passive_10"]:checked~.fullverbtable_2 {
  display: flex;
}

label {
  font-family: 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #ff4b54;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 0px 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="inputs">
  <label for="aimer_larousse_ef_active_10">Conjugaison (voix active)</label>
  <input type="radio" id="aimer_larousse_ef_active_10" name="trigger" class="trigger">
  <label for="aimer_larousse_ef_passive_10">Conjugaison (voix passive)</label>
  <input type="radio" id="aimer_larousse_ef_passive_10" name="trigger" class="trigger">

  <div class="fullverbtable_1">abcaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div>
  <div class="fullverbtable_2">xyzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz</div>
</div>
<div class="para">

</div>
```

If you want to expand all of them at the same time you can simply replace `radio` type to `checkbox`

```css
.trigger {
  display: none;
}

label {
  cursor: pointer
}

.fullverbtable_1,
.fullverbtable_2 {
  display: none;
}

input[id="aimer_larousse_ef_active_10"]:checked~.fullverbtable_1,
input[id="aimer_larousse_ef_passive_10"]:checked~.fullverbtable_2 {
  display: flex;
}

label {
  font-family: 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #ff4b54;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 0px 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="inputs">
  <label for="aimer_larousse_ef_active_10">Conjugaison (voix active)</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="aimer_larousse_ef_active_10" name="trigger" class="trigger">
  <label for="aimer_larousse_ef_passive_10">Conjugaison (voix passive)</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="aimer_larousse_ef_passive_10" name="trigger" class="trigger">

  <div class="fullverbtable_1">abcaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div>
  <div class="fullverbtable_2">xyzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz</div>
</div>
<div class="para">

</div>
```

Comment: Excellent solution but won't work if he needs to expand multiple at the same time